# Magento Products Export Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I have about `65K SKU's`, When i'm trying to import through data profile it generate about 7k record in `Dataflow Batch Export` Table in `mysql` and then just show `500 internal server error` page,

`memory_limit 2048M`

`php_value max_execution_time 180000`

i have above `memory` and `execution` time setting for store.

Any suggestion or idea what is causing error.

Thank you

Comment: 500 error could be a million things, please find the error and add it to the question and specify if you are using apache or nginx (in bginx you need a little extra configuration to get it work) BTW the error logs are usually in /var/log/nginx or /var/php/xxx but could be overwritten in vhots.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use ImportExport module instead Dataflow (I know that is a little more complex) but the difference o resources consumption and time worth it.

Edit:

Sometimes if you have too many attributes and attributes sets Mysql could exceeds the maximum of joins allowed in a query. So try to export them by sets (not the entire catalog at once).